# c# installer project with external file

Tags: c#, installation

I have created an application in which every installation is differed by the configuration file. 
Currently the configuration file (settings.setting) is part of the installer itself.
Is there a way to create an installer without the settings.setting embedded inside it, so will have the setup.exe and a separate settings.setting file?
(So will have 1 installation build, and the installation will copy the setting file to the relevant location as done if it is part of the installation build)

Thanks,
Yoav

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to extract the config file to another file and link it from default config file.

`MyApp.exe.config` would containt a line like this:

```
<appSettings configSource="pathtoconfig\MyExternalAppSettings.config" />
```

[Here's](https://bhrnjica.net/2016/01/30/using-external-config-files-in-net-applications/) a good blog post on this subject.